# Eliminar elemento de JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente Json, que se utiliza para generar elementos de una ruleta.

```
 var elementosRuleta=[ 
          {
            'fillStyle': '#0B4B61',
            'text': 'I',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#4FC3EA',
            'text': 'R',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#EEA513',
            'text': 'T',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#F5F103',
            'text': 'U',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#99F30F',
            'text': 'S',
            'textFontSize': 12
          }
        ];
```

Después que se gira la ruleta, si por ejemplo sale la U como ganadora, deseo eliminarla del JSON. En este caso el JSON quedaría así:

```
 var elementosRuleta=[ 
          {
            'fillStyle': '#0B4B61',
            'text': 'I',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#4FC3EA',
            'text': 'R',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#EEA513',
            'text': 'T',
            'textFontSize': 14
          },
          {
            'fillStyle': '#99F30F',
            'text': 'S',
            'textFontSize': 12
          }
        ];
```

Así cuando vuelva a generar la ruleta, ya no saldrá la letra que salió anteriormente.

El problema que tengo es que en algunas ocasiones me despliega el error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined. Regularmente ocurre después de ejecutar el splice alguna vez.

Lo que deseo hacer, es si por ejemplo el random tiene por valor 1, elimine solo el primer elemento del json. Si sale 3, elimine solo el elemento 3 del json. Debo ir eliminando de 1 en 1, según la posición que sale en el random. Esto debo hacerlo así, para que los elementos que ya salieron en la ruleta, no se vuelvan a repetir. Hasta que el json quede sin ningún elemento.

El código que dejo de ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
var elementosRuleta = [{
    'fillStyle': '#0B4B61',
    'text': 'I',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#4FC3EA',
    'text': 'R',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#EEA513',
    'text': 'T',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#F5F103',
    'text': 'U',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#99F30F',
    'text': 'S',
    'textFontSize': 12
  }
];

function eliminar(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*elementosRuleta.length);
  $.each(elementosRuleta, function (i, item) { 
      if (item.text == elementosRuleta[random].text){
      console.log(item.text);
      elementosRuleta.splice(random,random);

      }
  });
  console.log(elementosRuleta);
}

$("#boton").click(function(){
    eliminar();
});
```

Por su ayuda, muchas gracias.

```js
var elementosRuleta = [{
    'fillStyle': '#0B4B61',
    'text': 'I',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#4FC3EA',
    'text': 'R',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#EEA513',
    'text': 'T',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#F5F103',
    'text': 'U',
    'textFontSize': 14
  },
  {
    'fillStyle': '#99F30F',
    'text': 'S',
    'textFontSize': 12
  }
];

function eliminar(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*elementosRuleta.length);
  $.each(elementosRuleta, function (i, item) { 
      if (item.text == elementosRuleta[random].text){
      console.log(item.text);
      elementosRuleta.splice(random,random);

      }
  });
  console.log(elementosRuleta);
}

$("#boton").click(function(){
 eliminar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="boton">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: no necesitas iterar tu lista de `elementosRuleta` para hacer el splice

Comment: tienes un problema en tu codigo, estas contando con un length y comparando contra esto , si lo ejecutas siempre te va a salir error, por que un array empieza desde 0 y no desde 1  si modificas tu codigo en el length con -1 se soluciona, y ten en cuenta la respuesta que dio **Paulo**

Comment: Está mal empleado el término JSON. Dice "Tengo el siguiente Json..." pero lo que se muestra es la declaración de una variale a la que se le asigna un objeto tipo Array cuyos elementos son objetos cuyas propiedades son literales. Una forma de corregir sería en lugar de decir Json, decir objeto, "Tengo el siguiente objeto..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)** lo estás tratando de esta manera `splice(random, random)` lo que se traduce en que estás comenzando a eliminar el objeto desde un índice específico, pero a su vez eliminas la cantidad de ese índice, es decir, *si el random vale 0, no eliminará nada, si vale 3 eliminará 3 objetos*, etc.

Así que sólo deberías cambiar la lógica de eso por un

```
elementosRuleta.splice(random, 1)
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Hola @Paulo gracias, lo que deseo hacer, es si por ejemplo el random tiene por valor 1, elimine solo el primer elemento del json. Si sale 3, elimine solo el elemento 3 del json. Debo ir eliminando de 1 en 1, según la posición que sale en el random. Esto debo hacerlo así, para que los elementos que ya salieron en la ruleta, no se vuelvan a repetir. Hasta que el json quede sin ningun elemento.

Comment: Esta respuesta te sirve , si utilizas el `splice` el **primer** parametro que le defines es el `item` o `index` del `array` a borrar y el **segundo** parámetro es la cantidad de `items` que deseas borrar a partir del primero, por eso debes poner **1** para que solo borre el `item` que necesitas si pones **3,3** lo que va hacer es borrar a partir del `item` **3** otros dos mas.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad lo que tienes es un array de objetos literales de Javascript, en ese caso [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) es una posible solución, acá te dejo otra posible solución una usando [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), la ventaja sería que podrias eliminar un elemento a aprtir de una propiedad de los objetos.

```js
var elementosRuleta = [{"fillStyle":"#0B4B61","text":"I","textFontSize":14},{"fillStyle":"#4FC3EA","text":"R","textFontSize":14},{"fillStyle":"#EEA513","text":"T","textFontSize":14},{"fillStyle":"#F5F103","text":"U","textFontSize":14},{"fillStyle":"#99F30F","text":"S","textFontSize":12}];

function eliminar() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementosRuleta.length);
  elementosRuleta = elementosRuleta.filter((e, i) => i !== random);
  console.log(elementosRuleta)
}

$("#boton").click(function() {
  eliminar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="boton">Click Me!</button>
```

si usas `splice(a,b)` **a** sería el indice y **b** sería la cantidad a eliminar.